# Nginx uswgi django subpath without uwsgi_modifier1 30;

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I've to deploy a django app running under a subpath.

this is my uswgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = :3031
http= :9000
chdir = .
wsgi-file = docker.wsgi
processes = 4
threads = 2
stats = :9191
enable-threads = true
```

and this my nginx conf file

```
server {
    location /my/subpath {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass django:3031;
    }
}
```

now with this configuration django fails to match the urls since it expect to be accepting request at `/` and not at `/my/subpath`

If i modify the nginx conf as this:

```
server {
    location /my/subpath {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass django:3031;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /my/subpath;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }
}
```

**it works, BUT**

> Note: ancient uWSGI versions used to support the so called
>   “uwsgi_modifier1 30” approach. Do not do it. it is a really ugly hack
>   ([source](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html))

I can't get my head around on how to configure nginx to make it working.

From the documentation of uwsgi there's the possibility to use `mount` point, but even with that i can't figure out how I should change the uwsgi.ini file to make it working.

Honestly, I would like to fix only the nginx file and not the uwsgi.ini if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem but I resolved it by adding to `uswgi.ini` file this lines:

```
mount = /api=<project_name>.wsgi:application
manage-script-name = true
```